# LDAP / AD: Creating group A and adding it to group B fails

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, active-directory-group

I'm trying to create groupA, and add it to groupB. This fails, saying groupA cannot be found (although I can verify that it really is created). There appears to be a delay between the creation of the group and the point where it can be found by a search. Here's my code:

```
//1) create groupA
using (var group = ou.Children.Add("CN=" + AdConnection.EscapeLdapString(groupAName), "group"))
{
    group.Properties["samAccountName"].Value = groupAName;
    group.CommitChanges();
}

//2) add groupA to groupB
using (var pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain.Name, domain.Username, domain.Password))
{
    using (var groupB = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(pc, IdentityType.Guid, Guid))
    {
        groupB.Members.Add(pc, IdentityType.SamAccountName, groupAName); //throws a NoMatchingPrincipalException 
        groupB.Save();
    }
}
```

If I write this as two programs, and execute part 1, wait a while, and then later execute part 2, this works. I could probably repeatedly run part 2 until group A is found, but I'd like to avoid that. Is there any deterministic way to do this? For example, can I specify that groupA is a member of groupB as I create it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this by creating groupA with `new GroupPrincipal(pc, groupName)`, saving it, and then looking for groupB using the same PrincipalContext.